# Permutation superpatterns (all permutations of length $n^2$ which contain all $n!$ patterns of $n$).

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I wish to describe a permutation of length $n^{2}$ which contain all $n!$ patterns of $n$ for arbitrary $n$. This is a question from "A Walk Through Combinatorics" by Bona. Unfortunately there's not really much in the book about superpatterns. I had an idea of arranging a permutation of length $n^2$ by increasing order, then decreasing order. So for example let $n=2$, we need a permutation of length 4 that contains all 2 patterns. My idea is to arrange a permutation like this:

$(1243)$

The process would be to take the permutation $(123...n^2)$ and split it like $(1,2,3,...,n, n^2, (n^2-1),...,(n+1))$

Does this work? I am unsure how to prove it. Thank you.

See the example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superpattern to see what I'm talking about

**edit** I see now my test permutation does not work. Since if we have a permutation of length $n$ which increases, decreases, then increases again it will not work.

**SOLUTION** the lexicographic ordering on the coordinate vectors of points in a square grid

Comment: what does a patter mean in this context? at first I thought the numbers where only from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: Yes, I've added this to the main post. See the example in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superpattern

Comment: Arratia's original paper and construction is pretty short and easy to follow http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v6i1n1/pdf